# Safari vertically misaligns the value of an input field and won't let me use padding

Tags: html, css, safari

I am using Angular to create a filter for our Website. One of the filters is a video length filter, where you can input the desired length in minutes. The input field has the following Styles (Stylus):

```
border: 1px solid rgba(85, 85, 71, .5)
border-radius: 5px
color: #009090
display: block
font-size: 58px
height: 56px
line-height: 72px
margin-top: 40px
padding-bottom: 10px
width: 96px

&:focus
  border: 1px solid #009090
  outline: none
```

It works as expected in Chrome and Firefox:

[image: Chrome]

But Safari misaligns the content:

[image]

The padding-bottom, which centers the content for Chrome and Firefox seems to have no effect on Safari (and the effect of 10px is anyway less smaller than the huge misplacement that happens on Safari). I also tried **every possible combination of line-height, font-size, margins and paddings** but had no luck.

Strange is also that the blinking cursor seems to be well aligned in Safari, when nothing is put in:

[image: Cursor in Safari]

Although the input is misaligned, the cursor stays perfectly centered vertically:

[image: centered cursor in Safari]

Safari seems to add a *"Shadow-Content (User Agent)"* to the input field which is well aligned then (but is strange anyway, because an input-element cannot have children):

[image: Safari shadow content without input]

As soon as I type something in, the input is misaligned again and won't let me style the contents of the shadow-DOM (note the little locks in the Developer tools):

[image: Safari shadow content with input]

I really don't know **how to vertically center the text inside the input in Safari**. Has anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

THat's due to the discepancy between `height` and `line-height`:

```
height: 56px
line-height: 72px
```

The line won't fit into the container that way. `line-height` should at maximum be as high as `height`, and preferably the same as `font-size`. Also paddings add to the height, so adjust these values accordingly.

Comment: I tried all values of line-heights, also 56px but the problem stays the same.